# Maintaining state between browser tabs in PHP

Tags: php, session

I'm building a web application that allows users to run a query against one of two databases. They are only allowed to submit 1 query to each database at a time. Currently, I'm setting $_SESSION['runningAdvancedQuery'] (for instance) to let me know if they're running a query. This is to prevent someone from opening up a 2nd browser tab and hitting the resource again. It works great except...

If I start a query in a tab, then close that tab before it finishes, the flag does not get unset. Therefore, if I reopen the page, I cannot run any queries because it thinks I have one still running. Anyone have advice for getting around this?

Comment: when do you clear $_SESSION['runningAdvancedQuery'] ?

Comment: An AJAX call is made from the browser to initiate the query. When it's done, another AJAX call is made to retrieve and show the results. The flag is unset after showing the results.

Comment: Do you run query in thread? or there remains the Ajax call pending.

Comment: The AJAX call continues running.

Answer (score 1):

Set this value not to for example 1, but to unix timestamp, and do checking by comprasion last-query-timestamp to now, setting up some time difference that must go by to execute next query. Remeber to set a block-time to safe value - longest time which query can be executed. If user closes his tab, after a short time he will be "unlocked".

Comment: This could work, but I can see the client complaining about having to wait. Also, the query times are highly variable.

Comment: maybe try to detect closing tab:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

Comment: It was more the comment than the actual answer. That link you provided led me to learn this:

"the next time your script tries to output something PHP will detect that the connection has been aborted and the shutdown function is called"

Performing the operations in a shutdown function seems to do what I need (especially since the script doesnt terminate until the query finishes anyway)

Comment: Never mind, spoke too soon. The function connection_aborted() keeps returning 0...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);

//if session variable is not set
    //set session variable
    //run query
    //unset session variable
//else
    //show error: "your other query isn't finished yet"

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting `$_SESSION['runningAdvancedQuery'];`  to true, you could set it to the output of `SELECT CONNECTION_ID();`, and check `show processlist;` whether it's still running. This would be an addon to the other answers though: especially when using persistent connections other processes could have the connection_id in use.

As the same user, you are always allowed to see your own processes. So, to combine the other checks:

1. Store timestamp, connection_id & actual sql-query (I'd remove all white-space & cast to either upper or lower string to avoid slight differences in presentation to matter).
2. Of course use the ignore_user_abort() functionality, do a `session_write_close()` before the query, restart the session & set it to finished after the query.
3. On a check for the running query, check whether

   - The connection-id is still present.
   - The timestamp + seconds the query is running are reasonably close to the current time.
   - The query (lowercase, stripped whitespace) is about the same query as requested (use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` to get the whole query).

Optionally, take it a step further, and give people the possibility to `KILL  QUERY <connection_id>;` (only if the previous 3 checks all resulted in a positive).